# htaccess redirect folder and subfolders to one url only

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I must be the first person to be frustrated with htaccess redirects lol.

Have searched and can't find the solution to this:

I've got several 404s like this:

```
https://www.example.com/category/uncategorized/page/4/detox
https://www.example.com/category/uncategorized/page/5/detox
https://www.example.com/category/uncategorized/page/6/detox
https://www.example.com/category/uncategorized/page/7/detox
```

I want to redirect like this:

FROM

```
https://www.example.com/category/uncategorized/
```

and all subfolders or pages under this

TO

```
https://www.example.com/category/alcohol-drug-rehab/
```

(this exact url only and all subfolders should redirect to this subfolder)

I've tried

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/category/uncategorized/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/category/alcohol-drug-rehab/
```

...and several other variations.

However this results in redirections like this:

```
https://www.example.com/category/alcohol-drug-rehab/page/4/detox
https://www.example.com/category/alcohol-drug-rehab/page/5/detox
https://www.example.com/category/alcohol-drug-rehab/page/6/detox
https://www.example.com/category/alcohol-drug-rehab/page/7/detox
```

How do I alter the redirect to stop the rewritten url showing the subfolders after, and just redirect to the page only, at https://www.example.com/category/alcohol-drug-rehab/?

Would prefer straight forward rewrite statements if possible as opposed to mod rewrites, thanks.

Thanks

Comment: Try to add ? at the end of rule , empty browser cache the test

Comment: Hi, thanks, tried this, no joy, still redirects to an error page by adding on the subfolders at the end: https://www.example.com/category/alcohol-drug-rehab/page/7/detox

Comment: did you empty browser cache?

Comment: yes, cache cleared

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore anything trailing the initial path:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?category/uncategorized/ https://www.example.com/category/alcohol-drug-rehab/ [R=301,QSD]
```

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: HI thanks for this, sadly it didn't work.

So 

https://www.example.com/category/uncategorized/page/4/detox

still redirects to 

https://www.example.com/category/alcohol-drug-rehab/page/4/detox

It's in the htaccess file, and Rewrite Engine is on. All other types of redirects are working ok, just this one that's not.

Grateful for any ideas. Or is it a case of going back to the host at this stage.

Thanks

Comment: The above rule does _not_ redirect to `/category/alcohol-drug-rehab/page/4/detox`. You are either looking at a cached result (check your browsers network console to find out if you really receive a redirection or if the result is loaded from cache, also try an anonymous browser window). It might also be that some other rule is responsible for that redirection, but certainly not the rule given here.

Comment: ok, thanks for this, I'll take a look again at any conflicting redirects that might be present.